# Как с html кода получить только url адрес ссылки

Tags: php

Имею такую структуру, как с этого кода вытянуть только url самой ссылки?

```
 $link = '<a href="https://t-do.ru/telegramm" target="_blank">
     <img src="/img/socico/telegram.png" alt="">
 </a>';
```

Comment: Не надо делать костыли. Если вы отправляете это сообщение, сначала в отдельную переменную вынесите url, а затем вставляйте эту переменную в ваш код

Answer (score 0):

Сделал пока что так

```
$link = '<a href="https://t-do.ru/telegramm" target="_blank"><img src="/img/socico/telegram.png" alt=""></a>';

preg_match_all("/<[Aa][\s]{1}[^>]*[Hh][Rr][Ee][Ff][^=]*=[ '\"\s]*([^ \"'>\s#]+)[^>]*>/", $link, $matches);
```